# when check Duplicate value in array it shows undefine

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-zorro-antd

When I save the duplicate value in the role from the role from shown an error for duplicate data entry but I didn't show it.
[This image shows when I press any value in the text box it shows my console can not read properly roles of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3BYJ.png)

[image]

> Role.component.ts

```
export class RoleCreateComponent implements OnInit {

 roles: Role[] = [];

constructor(  private roleStorageService: RoleStorageService,
              private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.roles = this.roleService.getRoles();
    if (this.roles.length === 0) {
      this.roleStorageService.getRolesFromServer().subscribe();
    }
  }

  validacija(control: FormControl) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.roles.length; i++) {
      if (this.roles[i].name === control.value) {
        alert('The name already exist')
    }
  }
}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.roleForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [null],
      name: [null, [Validators.required], [this.validacija]],
    });
  }
}
```

> Role.component.html

```
    <nz-form-item>
      <nz-form-label [nzSpan]="null" nzRequired> Name</nz-form-label>
      <nz-form-control nzHasFeedback nzValidatingTip="Validating..." [nzErrorTip]="roleErrorTpl">
        <input nz-input formControlName="name" placeholder="Role Name" />
        <ng-template #roleErrorTpl let-control>
          <ng-container *ngIf="control.hasError('required')">
            Please input  name!
          </ng-container>
           <ng-container *ngIf="control.hasError('duplicated')">
            The Role is redundant!
          </ng-container>
        </ng-template>
      </nz-form-control>
    </nz-form-item>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Function Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context).

You should use a arrow function to keep `this` refers to your component instance.

```js
// ...
name: [null, [Validators.required], [ctrl => this.validacija(ctrl)]],
// ...
```

BTW, a validator should return a `ValidationErrors` or `null`. For example:

```js
// inside a validator function...
if (isValid) {
  return null;
}
return { duplicated: 'The name already exist' };
// ...
```

You can find more information about custom validator [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators)

Comment: when I use that it shows me  
 Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.

Comment: @Md.ArifShakilNobin I've updated my answer, that may help you